# Remove Jobs I have been rejected from/are not interested in from search results and from right-hand bar

Tags: feature-request

It is pretty demoralizing to keep seeing that "Featured" job I was rejected from on the right next every question I view on stackoverflow. Also, when searching for jobs, it would be nice to be able to eliminate jobs I am not qualified for or have been rejected from. I would be able to see the relevant jobs much more quickly.